# How to catch SIGSEGV of any program?

Tags: linux, signals, fedora

There are program named abrt (https://fedorahosted.org/abrt/) in Fedora and Fedora based distributions.
It catches fatal signals system wide, saves coredump and analyzes it.

- How can abrt catch signals of other programs? As far as I know you can catch only signals to your process.
- How abrt saves core file after it caught signal if ulimit -c is set to 0 by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't catch signals, and it doesn't read core files. Instead, ABRT uses `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to grab the core file as the kernel is generating it.

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp /var/spool/abrt %p %s %u %c
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. But why kernel generates core if ulimit -c is 0 by default?